# NodeJS + Socket.IO + Websocket + Flash - transfer the project to a hosting

Tags: flash, node.js, hosting, websocket, socket.io

I created a simple project of realtime game using NodeJS + Socket.IO + Websocket + Flash. Everything works fine on my PC (localhost). 
Temporarily place the project on a free hosting cloudno.de. Did not work.

I use these files:
server.js - file server nodejs (this file has not changed for hosting, because this port (8275) was nominated my application by hosting):

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
  http = require('http');

var fs = require('fs'),
  util = require('util');

var url = require('url'),
  path = require('path'),
  mime = require('mime');

function findType(uri) {
  var ext = uri.match(/\.\w+$/gi);
  if (ext && ext.length > 0) {
    ext = ext[0].split(".")[1].toLowerCase();
    return mime.lookup(ext);
  }
  return undefined;
}

function sendError(code, response) {
  response.writeHead(code);
  response.end();
  return;
}

    var app = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
      var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
      if (uri === '/') {
        uri = '/index.html';
      } else if (uri === '/server.js') {
        sendError(404, response);
        return;
      }
      var _file = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);

      path.exists(_file, function(exists) {
        if (!exists) {
          sendError(404, response);
        } else {
          fs.stat(_file, function(err, stat) {
            var file = __dirname + uri,
                type = findType(uri),
                size = stat.size;
            if (!type) {
              sendError(500, response);
            }
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':type + "; charset=utf-8", 'Content-Length':size});
            console.log("START");
            var rs = fs.createReadStream(file);
            util.pump(rs, response, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("ReadStream, WriteStream error for util.pump");
                response.end();
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });

    });

var socket = io.listen(app, {transports:['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'xhr-polling']}),
  buffer = [],
  MAXBUF = 1024,
  json = JSON.stringify;

var clients = [];
clients.usernames = function(client) {
  return client.username;
}

socket.sockets.on('connection', function(client) {
console.log("CONNECTED");
  client.on('message', function(data) {
      //skipped more line of code

  client.on('disconnect', function() {
    if (client.username) {
      client.json.broadcast.send({announcement:(client.username)+' left game', id:(client.id)});
    }
    var pos = clients.indexOf(client);
    if (pos >= 0) {
      clients.splice(pos, 1);
    }
  });});

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(8275);
  console.log("Socket-Chat listening on port 8275.. Go to http://<this-host>:8275");
}
```

index.html - the client file. Here are some of its code to connect Websocket.

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="web_socket.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript"  charset="utf-8">

    // Set URL of your WebSocketMain.swf here:
    WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION = "WebSocketMain.swf";
    // Set this to dump debug message from Flash to console.log:
    WEB_SOCKET_DEBUG = true;

    // Everything below is the same as using standard WebSocket.
    var ws;

    function init() {
      // Connect to Web Socket.
      // Change host/port here to your own Web Socket server.
      ws = new WebSocket("ws://myapp.cloudno.de");//on localhost i use "localhost:8275" and will be change before transfer 
      // Set event handlers.
      ws.onopen = function() {
        output("onopen");
      };
      ws.onmessage = function(e) {
        // e.data contains received string.
        output("onmessage: " + e.data);
      };
      ws.onclose = function() {
        output("onclose");
      };
      ws.onerror = function() {
        output("onerror");
      };

    }

    function onSubmit() {
      var input = document.getElementById("input");
      // You can send message to the Web Socket using ws.send.
      ws.send(input.value);
      output("send: " + input.value);
      input.value = "";
      input.focus();
    }

    function onCloseClick() {
      ws.close();
    }

    function output(str) {
      var log = document.getElementById("log");
      var escaped = str.replace(/&/, "&amp;").replace(/</, "&lt;").
        replace(/>/, "&gt;").replace(/"/, "&quot;"); // "
      log.innerHTML = escaped + "<br>" + log.innerHTML;
    }

  </script>
```

web_socket.js - the script has not changed and is taken entirely from the project: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

WebSocketMain.swf - this file is not changed, also from https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

SocketGame.swf - this is the main file of my game from this example https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO. This changed only one line:
socket = new FlashSocket("myapp.cloudno.de");//on localhost i use "localhost:8275" and will be change before transfer to the hosting

Can you please tell whether I have changed the configuration for hosting? For reference, the server logs for hosting and for localhost. The difference is noticeable immediately, but it is not clear why this is happening.

Hosting console log:

27 Dec 09:19:49 - Cloudnode wrapped script starting (30128) at Tue Dec 27 2011 09:19:49 GMT+0100 (UTC)
[36minfo  -[39m socket.io started
27 Dec 09:19:49 - [INFO] Cloudnode listening on port: 8275
Socket-Chat listening on port 8275.. Go to http://:8275
START
START
START
START
[90mdebug -[39m served static content /socket.io.js
START
START
[90mdebug -[39m client authorized
[36minfo  -[39m handshake authorized 1357476841432378537

Localhost console log:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\14l>node server.js
info  - socket.io started
Socket-Chat listening on port 8275.. Go to http://:8275
START
debug - served static content /socket.io.js
START
START
START
debug - client authorized
info  - handshake authorized 3511308552126147045
debug - setting request GET /socket.io/1/flashsocket/3511308552126147045
debug - set heartbeat interval for client 3511308552126147045
debug - client authorized for
debug - flashsocket writing 1::
CONNECTED

After starting my application occurs handshake and everything stopped - the connection fails. I changed a lot of options - nothing helps.

I suspect that problem or socket.io (but I simply copied the module working with my computer), or Flash security policy. But how to use it in my particular case is not clear. 
Here is the module that should help (https://github.com/3rd-Eden/FlashPolicyFileServer), but how to integrate it into my project?

I would be very grateful for the clarification.

Comment: Why aren't you using Socket.IO on the frontend, but you're using instead the basic WS? (which will only work in Chrome and maybe another 1-2 browsers depending on settings)

Comment: Because i do not know any other ways to pass from JS (Socket.IO client) data in the Flash client (move hero, monsters, bullet) from another Flash. P2P easy to fake.

Comment: If you want to use WebSockets from a Flash environment, [Kaazing](http://kaazing.com) has extensive support for it. Disclaimer: I work for Kaazing.

Answer (score 3):

Alessioalex kind of nailed it.  Your client side code isn't taking advantage of socket.io to do the flash socket / xhr stuff you're looking to do.  You really want to use socket.io on the client:

http://socket.io/#how-to-use

The other issue you're likely to run into is a lack of support for WebSockets on your host.  Heroku currently suffers from this, and they suggest just rolling with xhr:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku

The FlashSocketPolicy integration should be pretty easy.  You just need to npm install the module, import it in your app.js, and start listening.  The example in the github repo was pretty simple:

https://github.com/3rd-Eden/FlashPolicyFileServer/blob/master/examples/basic.js

Hope this all helps a little, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you Justin. I got to know with all nodejs instructions a lot of days, but it does not help because it is difficult to learn server-side scripts, when is a flash developer. I found this example (https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO) and made the chat, one day I created a realtime multiplayer game and it worked fine on my computer, but there were problems with the transfer to the hosting. Since hosting is free (I do not want to buy nodejs hosting with no prospects), then there is no technical support.

Comment: I tried FlashPolicyFileServer, but it causes an error (TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listen') to the line pf.listen (); I also tried this solution https://github.com/freeformsystems/node-fxs. Also there is no result, either an error or permission denied. Maybe it's some kind of limitation of free hosting. As to the refusal of Websockets, I use Flash and do not know any other ways to pass from JS (Socket.IO client) data in the Flash client (move hero, monsters, bullet) from another Flash.

Comment: Huh, it's sad that Flash policy module doesn't work - I've had to do some crazy stuff to get around that in the past, and was kind of excited when I saw someone had made a module for it.  As far as passing data from JS to Flash - that's the easy part :-)  You use ExternalInterface:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf626ae-7fe8.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f31

Comment: This is probably only my problem. Actually discovered that my hosting service uses a node-http-proxy that have problems with websockets https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/97. ExternalInterface sends data and receives callback from JS, but have not seen how it can receive data from the JS from which you do not wait callback. While this is certainly very easy to experiment. Thank you.